# Assigning a string from one variable into another, array variable

Tags: objective-c

What is the proper way of assigning the string in ZNstartTime to args[0]? Thank you.

```
char *args[10];

- (void)print:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {

    NSString *ZNstartTime =  [arguments objectAtIndex:1];  //contents is "string"     
    NSString *ZNlengthTime = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];  //contents is "string" 


       args[0] = ZNstartTime //<-- returning incompatible error

}
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString*` has to be converted to a `char*` using `[ZNstartTime cStringUsingEncoding:ASCIIEncoding]`

Comment: @cube - try `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: When I do this I get `ASCIIEncoding undeclared`.